# Unable to resolve dependency tree react

Tags: reactjs, npm

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: project@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0" from react-spinners@0.11.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-spinners
npm ERR!   react-spinners@"^0.11.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Muhammad\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Muhammad\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-19T06_37_06_899Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0):

use npm with --legacy-peer-deps like this `npm install yourpackage --legacy-peer-deps`